# Windows 10 - Run all programs as elevated AND run basic programs using Built-in-Administrator?

Tags: windows, windows-10, uac

*After reading a lot of answers ([example](https://superuser.com/questions/1025619/settings-cant-be-opened-using-the-built-in-administrator-account-in-windows-10)) , I didn't find one that supply the whole solution to my problem.*

**Brief :**

My problem basically is that If i'm setting the policy to run every program as elevated , then - in that case it does work , but then I can't run basic programs like `calc.exe`.

**Details :**

I have windows 10 pro. My user name is `Dalits` . I'm in the administrator's group :

[image]

Running `secpol.msc`  — this is the settings of UAC :

[image]

Ok so let's `start->run->cmd.exe` :

[image]

Great. it runs as admin.

But Now I want `calc.exe` (`start->run->calc.exe`) :

[image]

**Question**

How can I configure my Win10 to run all programs as elevated **AND** allow basic programs like `calc.exe` (etc , I mean all programs) to run also.

Comment: UWP require UAC to be enabled.  The built-in Administrator has limitations when it comes to UWP.  So your goal of  "all programs" is not realistic for that reason.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm a simple guy, can it be done ? I want my admin account to have power as it should.

Comment: You **cannot** use UWP and disable UAC the way you have done.

Comment: @Ramhound 1- where do you see that ive disabled UAC ? 2- what is UWP ? ;)

Comment: UWP stands for Universal Windows Program.  By default the built-in Administrator UAC  prompt is set at a different level, that level, means it cannot run Universal Windows Programs.

Comment: @Ramhound why an admin at that level wasn't programmed to run those programs? He is an admin !...

Comment: Contact Microsoft if you want to know the reason, that by default, the built-in Administrator isn't capable of running UWP which means various default applications cannot be run by that account.  I have a general idea of the reason, but that conclusion is based on years of experience, and its simply an opinion which is about as useful as that thing your sitting on.

Comment: I was able to get this to work by also setting the above policy **User Account Control: Run all administrators in Admin Approval Mode** to **Disabled** and restarting the computer. Start → Run → `cmd.exe` now runs as Administrator. UWP `calc.exe` also runs fine, because in Windows 10 1703, Microsoft lifted the earlier restriction where UWP apps would only run if UAC was on. I'm using Windows 10 2004 (19041.329).

Answer (score 1):

You can add a registry entry that will allow an administrator account to run applications that are otherwise blocked (calc, edge, etc.):

With regedit, browse to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

Create a new 32 Bit DWORD entry named `FilterAdministratorToken`and set it's value to 1.

Reboot, and it *should* work.

[Source](http://winaero.com/blog/fix-apps-and-start-menu-do-not-open-under-administrator-account-in-windows-10/)

Disclaimer - I last tried this on one of the original win 10 releases when logged in directly as the built-in Administrator account; its entirely possible the security model has changed.

Comment: All the registry tweak does in this case is actually enable UAC turning the built-in Administrator into a semi-weaker Administrator user account.  I cannot in good faith say that its a good idea to enable, the only Administrator account that always exists, and then use it daily.  If something happens to every single Administrator account and the built-in Administrator account is always broken, there is no recourse, the only solution would be to install Windows again.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment - but it does resolve the issue raised in the question. I'm not questioning his/her motive for wanting to do that. There is (almost) always a valid use case for every crazy config, eg a well sand boxed VM. Regardless, good point.

Comment: I don't see it as crazy config . Allowing a single admin , the only user to run uwp and other softs as an admin is a basic thing . Win 8 didnt has that problem.

Comment: Did you try that setting? If so, did it do what you are looking for?

Comment: Im not near my computer

Comment: Update 25/7/2016 - - this doesn't work anymore. Still prevent basic programs like calc etc.  im back to the prev settigns .https://i.imgur.com/i2QNneW.png